# Starting OpenVPN won't let me access local network IPs

Tags: 14.04, networking, samba, openvpn

OpenVPN is installed via apt-get.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start # works
```

Now if I try to access, for example, my NAS device web page (or even the network share over afp:// or smb://) at https://192.168.0.2 (its static IP which works from other machines), connections time out. It can't seem to find that particular IP.

Now, if I run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn stop
```

And repeat the process, I can access the IP address and all shares just fine.

My guess is that the OpenVPN configuration is somehow telling the OS to look at a different gateway IP that knows nothing about my local router, but I don't know how to confirm that, nor do I know how to change it.

Advice appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am more familiar with *openvpn* via *network-manager*.

But what is likely to happen is that *openvpn* is adding new IP route (for the VPN *tunnel*) and even remove the existing one to your local network.

You can check that by running:

```
ip route
```

before and after having started openvpn.

If the route to your LAN disappeared, you can manually add again a route to your local LAN with:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0
```

assuming you LAN is on `192.168.0.0/24` and your network interface is *eth0*

You can test the access to your LAN by using the ping command.

```
ping 192.168.0.2
```